# How to properly call/trigger functions on a page load?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am looking to implement pagination on the number of quotes in my Vue.Js app. I have built a function to split the quotes depending on what the `paginationLimit` is set to. but for some reason the `updateVisibleQuotes()` method does not split my initial `quotes_list` array.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    search: '',
    showMovieQuotes: false,
    showGameQuotes: false,
    quotes_list: [],
    visibleQuotesList: [],
    currentPage: 0,
    paginationLimit: 3,
  },
  mounted(){
    fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benchprep/dffc3bffa9704626aa8832a3b4de5b27/raw/quotes.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.quotes_list = data;
    })
    .then(
      this.updateVisibleQuotes()
    )
  },
  methods:{

    updatePage(pageNumber){
      this.currentPage = pageNumber;
      this.updateVisibleQuotes();
    },

    updateVisibleQuotes() {
      this.visibleQuotesList = this.quotes_list.splice(this.currentPage * this.paginationLimit, (this.currentPage * this.paginationLimit) + this.paginationLimit)
      console.log(this.visibleQuotesList);
      if (this.visibleQuotesList.length == 0 && this.currentPage > 0) {
        this.updatePage(this.currentPage - 1);
      }
    }
  },
  computed:{
    // Filters quotes by looping through quotes_list and matching whats in search
    filteredQuotes: function () {
      return this.quotes_list.filter((quote) =>{
        return quote.quote.match(this.search) ||  quote.theme.match(this.search)
      })
    },

  }
})
```

I am expecting the `visibleQuotesList` to be an array of 3 items after it is called in `mounted()` but instead i get an empty array.. Should i be calling my `updateVisibleQuotes` method inside the `mounted()` cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) takes a function/callback, so your last `.then()` call in the chain should be like:

```
.then(() => {
  this.updateVisibleQuotes()
});
```

Or simply,

```
.then(this.updateVisibleQuotes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
 .................
    beforeMount(){
        this.methodaname()
    }
.............
```

you have to define function name inside methods then call it inside beforeMount()